# Unable to update Eclipse / STS 3.7.3

Tags: eclipse, m2e, spring-tool-suite, sonatype

After fresh install of Spring Tool Suite 3.7.3 (and adding the Subclipse plugin), update comes up with the error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper,0.15.0.201212120353
No repository found containing: x,0.14.0.201509090157
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature,0.15.0.201212120353
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.sonatype.m2e.egit.feature,0.14.0.201509090157
```

M2E and Sonatype seem to be involved in this somehow.

How to get rid of this error? And what about the missing "x" artifact?

Answer (score 0):

Going to Help -> Installation details and uninstalling several components that related to M2E and Sonatype got me rid of this error message.